# When, if ever, is it justified to break normalization rules and replicate a field for efficiency?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, query-performance

Suppose I have two simple models, `Sentence`s and `Mentions`s, where each `Mention` is a reference to a mention of a in a `Sentence`. Let's say they have the following normalized schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sentence (id INT, doc_id TEXT, text TEXT)
CREATE TABLE mention (id INT, sentence_id INT, person_name TEXT)
```

Let's say that a significant fraction of all my queries filter `mention`s on `doc_id`. When, if ever, should I denormalize my schema and replicate `doc_id` as a field in `Mention`?

```
CREATE TABLE sentence (id INT, doc_id TEXT, text TEXT)
CREATE TABLE mention (id INT, sentence_id INT, doc_id TEXT, person_name TEXT)
```

If this case, would you recommend I use triggers or some other feature with postgres to ensure consistency?

**Some empirical observations**
I have some empirical observations on a small database with the above schema; the `sentence` table contains *39786* rows and the `mention` table contains *76385* rows. Below, I will report the query plan for different queries and execution times for `postgres`.

The main takeaways seem to be that if I create an index both on the querying field (`doc_id` here) and on the join columns (`sentence_id`), I can get comparable performance to replicating the field. Of course, it seems hard to beat creating an index on the replicated field.

**Replicating doc_id in mention with index**:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention WHERE doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Aggregate  (cost=239.31..239.32 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mention  (cost=4.97..239.13 rows=71 width=0)
         Recheck Cond: (doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mention_doc_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.95 rows=71 width=0)
               Index Cond:(doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention WHERE doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Time: 0.529 ms
```

**Replicated doc_id in mention without index**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention WHERE doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
 Aggregate  (cost=2368.99..2369.00 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on mention  (cost=0.00..2368.81 rows=71 width=0)
         Filter: (doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention WHERE doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Time: 12.619 ms
```

**Joining on sentence, no index**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
 Aggregate  (cost=10345.46..10345.47 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=7880.61..10345.35 rows=44 width=0)
         Hash Cond: (p.sentence_id = s.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on mention p  (cost=0.00..2177.85 rows=76385 width=4)
         ->  Hash  (cost=7880.32..7880.32 rows=23 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on sentence s  (cost=0.00..7880.32 rows=23 width=4)
                     Filter: (doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Time: 37.783 ms
```

**Joining on sentence, indexing only on join columns**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
 Aggregate  (cost=10345.46..10345.47 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=7880.61..10345.35 rows=44 width=0)
         Hash Cond: (p.sentence_id = s.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on mention p  (cost=0.00..2177.85 rows=76385 width=4)
         ->  Hash  (cost=7880.32..7880.32 rows=23 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on sentence s  (cost=0.00..7880.32 rows=23 width=4)
                     Filter: (doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Time: 37.783 ms
```

**Joining on sentence, indexing both doc_id and join columns**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
 Aggregate  (cost=542.06..542.07 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..541.95 rows=44 width=0)
         ->  Index Scan using sentence_doc_id_idx on sentence s  (cost=0.41..93.38 rows=23 width=4)
               Index Cond: (doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13'::text)
         ->  Index Only Scan using mention_sentence_id_idx on mention p  (cost=0.29..19.46 rows=4 width=4)
               Index Cond: (sentence_id = s.id)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mention p, sentence s WHERE p.sentence_id = s.id AND s.doc_id = 'APW_ENG_20070910.0871.LDC2009T13';
Time: 9.578 ms
```

Comment: Assuming that the relation between persons and sentences is a many-to-many your existing tables are not normalized. And a datatype like `TEXT` for an `id` is a bit strange.

Comment: I think you should add more details to you existing schema, how did you conclude that it is normalized (and to what degree, 3NF)?

Comment: Normalization rules refer to "harmful redundancy".  There are times when this sort of redundancy ends up doing more good than harm.  Data warehousing comes to mind.  But that's not relevant to your case in point.  It behooves the would-be expert designer to understand normalization, its benefits, and the benefits to alternative design disciplines.  You don't have to learn all of this at once.

Comment: It seems to me that person-referenced-in-sentence is many-to-many.  One sentence references several people.  Several sentences reference one person.  Your model doesn't accommodate that.

Comment: By the way, you don't need triggers to enforce consistency. You only need to add a UNIQUE key `sentence (doc_id, sentence_id)` and change the foreign key to `FOREIGN KEY (doc_id, sentence_id) REFERENCES sentence (doc_id, sentence_id)`

Comment: @WalterMitty: Ah, I agree that as described `person` should be many-to-many. I was adapting my use case where I actually have `mention`, which refers to a specific mention of a person. The `mention` table then has a foreign key for a unique person.

Comment: @dnoeth, Oops, sorry, I really meant for `id` to be `INT`, not `TEXT`.

Comment: @arunchaganty Can you update your question with those changes, that way people can give a better answer.

Comment: @Cody, agreed.  If we're looking at the wrong schema, we're going to come up with the wrong answer concerning normalization.

Answer (score -1):

Normalization are a set of techniques that, in a theoretical scenario, are intended to pursue consistency and ease of management and save costs. However, since you cannot work with a theoretical scenario, but with a real DBMS, you may find that a database with a certain high degree of normalization may be hard to use, and hard maintain in terms of coding and daily maintenance in a real-world scenario.

Said that you may find that, under certain circumstances, you can achieve the same goal of normalization by means of other techniques while not compromising computation cost or maintenance cost, and with an acceptable increase in storage cost. This is why, along with Normalization, there is another technique called Denormalization.

Of course you should do specific benchmarking tests and case studies to know which queries are the  most common ones, so you can choose which columns to denormalilze. For example, if you have a country with several different country specific columns, and you have the country id (say, an INT) as a FK in the rest of your tables, as probably that id is meaningless (as intended, since it is an ID), you may foresee that every single query will need to join with the country table to retrieve the country name. So you may want to denormalize the common country name, which is used for daily reporting, while you may find that you don't need to denormalize the formal country name, which is used much less common.

So analyzing the real use of your database you may try to improve their computational costs. After 17 years designing and managing databases, particularly in the DWH world, my rule of thumb is start at 3FN which to me is a good trade off between usability, consistency and computational, maintenance and storage costs.